# Adding text under Single Product Short Description of a specific catalog on woocommerce

Tags: woocommerce

I have 2 catalog

1. Catalog 1: 3d pop up cards. Slug:3d-pop-up-cards
2. Catalog 2: Phone Covers. Slug: Phone-Covers

I want to adding text under Single Product Short Description of Catalog 1 (3d Pop up cards).
I use this code but the text I want to add appear in both catalogs. Any idea of this problem pls!
My Added code here:

add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_product_summary', 2 );
function custom_single_product_summary(){
global $product;

```
remove_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'woocommerce_template_single_excerpt', 20 );
add_action( 'woocommerce_single_product_summary', 'custom_single_excerpt', 20 );
```

}

function custom_single_excerpt(){
global $post, $product;

```
$short_description = apply_filters( 'woocommerce_short_description', $post->post_excerpt );

if (( ! $short_description ) && (has_term( '3d-pop-up-cards', 'product_cat', $product->id )))
    return;

// The custom text
$custom_text = '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
<strong><span style="color: #ff0000;"><li>My Text Here</li></span></strong>
</ul>';

?>
<div class="woocommerce-product-details__short-description">
    <?php echo $short_description . $custom_text; // WPCS: XSS ok. ?>
</div>
<?php
```

}

Thanks everyone in advance for the help!
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6EqPu.jpg)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TlnpQ.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_short_description', 'woo_add_text_after_excerpt_single_product', 20, 1 );

function woo_add_text_after_excerpt_single_product( $custom_text ){

   // Your custom text
   $custom_text = '<ul class="fancy-bullet-points red">
        <li><strong><span style="color: #ff0000;">My Text Here</span></strong></li>
    </ul>';

  return $custom_text;
}
```