# placing a php code under the price in woocommerce

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I have an php code which I want to put in my product page.
but I want to place this PHP below the price. when I add this snippet to my "single-product-style3.php" file which represent my layout for product page, the code adds below my add to cart button but I want it to be under the price.
I have another code which I use for my "view cart" page.

Just to clarify everything here is two screenshot, I want the paybright text to be in the red spot.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/DBjeQ.jpg
https://i.stack.imgur.com/kprcK.jpg

Can someone help me please?
this is my website address: https://mayagallery.ca/
I wanted to know where should I upload and add this snippet:

```
<?php
function pb_modal() {
    $pb_product_price = get_post_meta( get_the_ID(), '_price', true);
    $pb_product_format = number_format((float)$pb_product_price, 2, '.', '');
    echo "<script id='pb_prequalify' type='text/javascript' src='https://app.paybright.com/dist/sdk.js?public_key=*******'></script>
<script>
    pb_prequalify_init();
</script>
<div id='paybright-widget-container'></div>";}
add_action( 'woocommerce_after_add_to_cart_form', 'pb_modal', 1);
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try this:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_get_price_html', 'woo_add_text_after_price_single_product', 20, 1 );

function woo_add_text_after_price_single_product($price){

// Your custom text
  $custom_text = '<span style="color: #ff0000;">My Custom Text Here...</span>';

   return $price.'<br>'.$custom_text;
}
```

Reference URL: https://stackoverflow.com/a/68936308/16560548

If you want to show test on shop page also you should try such type - https://stackoverflow.com/a/69025097/16560548

Comment: thank you for your help, the thing is I don't have a text, I have a PHP code, so could you please let me know where should I add the PHP code? and also on the cart page too. this code is for the product page, and I have the same code for the view cart page which I want to be under the proceed to checkout.

Comment: IF you can place PHP code so you need to override the single-product page and customer accordingly. first, create woocommerce folder name folder on your active theme and copy pages from plugin-> woocommerce -> templetes->single-product  and past on your theme woocommerce folder and customize pages pode accordingly